# Unsupported type for Fields (enum)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, objective-sharpie

I'm attempting to create a binding for an iOS Framework for Xamarin (generated by objective sharpie) and it's stumbling on the type of a field:

Structs.cs:

```
public enum FooType : byte
{
    A = 0,
    B = 1
}
```

ApiDefinition.cs:

```
[Static]
partial interface Constants
{
    // extern const FooType Foo;
    [Field("Foo", "__Internal")]
    FooType Foo { get; }
}
```

It's generating the error:

> Error BI1014: bgen: Unsupported type for Fields: FooType for 'Namespace.Constants Foo'.

Are enums not allowed in fields? How can I work around this error?

Edit: I found this setting, but it doesn't fix the error:
[image: Screenshot of setting]

Edit 2: Apparently the list of types that can be Fields are [quite limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference#FieldAttribute), perhaps I should convert the enum type to Int32?

> ```
> NSString
> NSArray
> nint / int / long
> nuint / uint / ulong
> nfloat / float
> double
> CGSize
> System.IntPtr
> Enums
> ```

Edit 3: Converting the enum type to Int32 worked, but is this valid? Will the code run correctly and return a valid value?

Comment: `enums not allowed in fields?` Yes they are. The code that you posted is valid (I even pasted/compiled it into a class to confirm): https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/docs/website/binding_types_reference_guide.md#fieldattribute